# Terminal zsh commands stopped working suddenly

Tags: terminal, zsh, terminal-services, zshrc

I was attempting to update my npm version and suddenly received errors and now my zsh commands stopped working. I attempted to move the PATH but noticed my path is strangely massive... How do i reset zsh and correct my path?

Path:

```
$ echo $PATH
/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/zchaney/bin
```

Comment: UPDATE: so tried executing the zsh file `exec usr/lib/zsh` still received error that it was not a command.